# iPhone + UITabBar

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar in my application with three tab bar items.

At certain cases I want to show all three tab bar items and some cases I want to hide the 3rd tab bar item from the Tabbar.

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the [setItems:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623455-setitems) message to the UITabBar. For example:

```
// get array of current UITabBarItem objects
NSMutableArray *tabBarItems = [tabBarViewController.items mutableCopy];

// modify the array (remove or add UITarBarItem objects as appropriate) here

// animate the changes to the UITabBar
[tabBarViewController.tabBar setItems:tabBarItems animiated:YES];
```

Comment: If create an NSArray, how can I modify it (add / remove objects from it) because its not mutable.